# the conflict between the main thread and AsyncTask<String, String, String>

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Here is my main code:

```
        buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
            userID = myApplication.getUserID();

            // 布局文件转换为view对象
            LayoutInflater inflaterDl = LayoutInflater
                    .from(BuyGoodsDetailActivity.this);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflaterDl.inflate(
                    R.layout.dialog, null);
            // 对话框
            final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    BuyGoodsDetailActivity.this).create();
            dialog.show();
            dialog.getWindow().setContentView(layout);

            TextView dialogTitle, dialogMessage, dialogMessageMid, 
                    dialogMessageRight, leftButtonText, rightButtonText;
            dialogTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
            dialogMessage = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_msg);
            dialogMessageMid = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialog_msg2);
            dialogMessageRight = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialog_msg3);
            // leftButtonText = (TextView)
            // layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_leftBtnTxt);
            rightButtonText = (TextView) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialog_rightBtnTxt);

            if (userID == 0) {
                Log.i(Tag, "userID == "+String.valueOf(userID));
                dialogTitle.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.dialog_login_title));
                dialogMessage.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.dialog_login_message));
                rightButtonText.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.dialog_login_rightButton));

                // 取消按钮
                RelativeLayout buttonLeft = (RelativeLayout) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.leftBtn);
                buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                // 确定按钮
                RelativeLayout buttonRight = (RelativeLayout) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.rightBtn);
                buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        dialogIntent = new Intent();
                        dialogIntent.setClass(BuyGoodsDetailActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(dialogIntent);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Log.i(Tag, "userID == "+String.valueOf(userID));
                new get_user_id_money().execute();
                Log.i(Tag, "the totalPrice original is: " + totalPrice);
                while(totalPrice == null){
                }
                Log.i(Tag, "the totalPrice is: " + totalPrice);
                Log.i(Tag, "the finalPriceTwoDecimal: " + finalPriceTwoDecimal);
                if (userTotalPrice < finalPriceTwoDecimal) {
                    dialogTitle.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_less_money_title));
                    dialogMessage.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_less_money_message));

                    float extraPay = finalPriceTwoDecimal - userTotalPrice;
                    dialogMessageMid.setText(String.valueOf(extraPay));
                    dialogMessageRight.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_less_money_message_more));
                    rightButtonText.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_less_money_rightButton));

                    // 取消按钮
                    RelativeLayout buttonLeft = (RelativeLayout) layout
                            .findViewById(R.id.leftBtn);
                    buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    // 确定按钮
                    RelativeLayout buttonRight = (RelativeLayout) layout
                            .findViewById(R.id.rightBtn);
                    buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            dialogIntent = new Intent();
                            dialogIntent.setClass(
                                    BuyGoodsDetailActivity.this,
                                    UserPurseActivity.class);
                            startActivity(dialogIntent);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    dialogTitle.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_buy_title));
                    dialogMessage.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_buy_message));
                    dialogMessageMid.setText(String
                            .valueOf(finalPriceTwoDecimal));
                    dialogMessageRight.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_less_money_message_more));
                    rightButtonText.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.dialog_buy_rightButton));

                    // 取消按钮
                    RelativeLayout buttonLeft = (RelativeLayout) layout
                            .findViewById(R.id.leftBtn);
                    buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    // 确定按钮
                    RelativeLayout buttonRight = (RelativeLayout) layout
                            .findViewById(R.id.rightBtn);
                    buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            new buy_product().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

and the AsyncTask is:
    class get_user_id_money extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String userIDString = String.valueOf(userID);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userIDString));

        MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        String url_get_user_id_money = myApplication.getIP()
                + "vendingmachine/user_id_money.php";

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_user_id_money,
                "GET", params);

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                totalPrice = json.getString("totalPrice");

                Log.i(Tag, "totalPrice is: " + totalPrice);
                userTotalPrice = Float.parseFloat(totalPrice);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

when running this code, here:

```
                    new get_user_id_money().execute();
                Log.i(Tag, "the totalPrice original is: " + totalPrice);
                while(totalPrice == null){
                }
                Log.i(Tag, "the totalPrice is: " + totalPrice);
                Log.i(Tag, "the finalPriceTwoDecimal: " + finalPriceTwoDecimal);
                if (userTotalPrice < finalPriceTwoDecimal) {
```

the totalprice is a string type

```
the userTotalPrice  = String.valueOf(totalprice)
```

but when i running this code, before the new get_user_id_money().execute(); completed, the main thread still running.

so i get this answer in the dialog: -106.79995

that means

```
userTotalPrice < finalPriceTwoDecimal
```

then running the if statement, the userTotalPrice gets it answer 109.95, the finalPriceTwoDecimal gets its answer: 3.15,

```
float extraPay = finalPriceTwoDecimal - userTotalPrice;
dialogMessageMid.setText(String.valueOf(extraPay));
```

so the answer will be -106.79995

i using the while statement lead to a dead cycle, but it doesn't work, what should i do?

i know the while statement is a also a very bad idea%>_<%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you move everything in if statement "if (userTotalPrice < finalPriceTwoDecimal)" into the onPostExecute method of your asynctask. The onPostExecute method is meant to update your UI. The while loop is not a good idea. Since you are getting the data in your asynctask you should do you checks in the same task. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: i know adding into the onPostExecute method of my asynctask, but the  if else statement is in a buyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() what i want to do is enter a button, check the status and shows different dialog, in different dialog, execute a different asynctask

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. Based on you code, I get that you are trying to set the params of you dialog box based on the if else statement. If you move the both he if else statement to the PostExecute it should work. you can show another dialog from the PostExecute

Comment: not exactly, there is a "buy" button, when i enter the button, i check whether or not the user is login, if not, it should show a dialog and lead to another activity to login, after login, the login activity finish(), back to the original activity, when logined, it will check the money in my account is or not more than the price of this commodity, so, first i need get the money from the database by using the userID and get the totalPrice, and then execute the if statement to check, if money is inadequate, it shows a dialog. if adequate, shows another dialog

Comment: so, even if i doesn't set the params of my dialog box based on the if else statement, it still wrong, because the if statement is unsatisfied, and will execute the else statement and show another dialog. All the if else statemtent is in a buyButton.setOnClickListener, which should be written in the onCreat method, right?

Comment: Since your only condition for the last 2 dialogs is whether the money is adequate or not, in you ` get_user_id_money` task, you can do the the check (if/else statement) in the PostExecute. you should have the money value for the if.

Comment: i know what you mean and modify my code, then it correctly, i have just reached a blind alley== thank you very much~